# Reading a 40GB ndjson file to google colab

Tags: python, json, file, google-colaboratory

I have to read a 40GB '.ndjson' file to google colab. But every time I use the google's T4 gpu, it runs out of RAM usage.

How can I read this large ndjson file and convert it to a '.csv' so that I have a dataframe to operate on?